# Dataset of health vitals from wearables

Tags: medical

Are there any places where I can find a combined dataset for health vitals like Body Temperature, Blood Pressure, Respiration, Glucose, Heart Rate, Oxygen Saturation, Electro Cardiogram etc. I am looking for such dataset to create a personal project.